# Blank Terminal Screen When Running Curses-Based Snake Game

Tags: c, ncurses

I am currently working on a simple snake game in C using the curses library. However, when I compile and execute the code to test if the snake marked 'S' would move, the terminal only displays a blank screen. I'm not sure what is causing this issue and I would like to fix it first.
So here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Define constants for height and width of the rectangle */
#define HEIGHT 20
#define WIDTH 60

/* Variables */
int gameover, x, y, fruitx, fruity, flag;

/* Function to position the fruit */
void position()
{
    gameover = 0;
    x = HEIGHT/2;
    y = WIDTH/2;
    fruitx = rand() % HEIGHT;
    fruity = rand() % WIDTH;
}

/* Function to draw a rectangle with specified height and width */
void boundary(int h, int w)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= h; i++) /* Rows */
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= w; j++) /* Columns */
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == h || j == 0 || j == w)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == x && j == y)
                {
                    printf("S");
                }
                else if (i == fruitx && j == fruity)
                {
                    printf("F");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Set movement */
void keyboard()
{
    int ch;

    switch(getch())
    {
    case KEY_UP:
        flag = 1;
        break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
        flag = 2;
        break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
        flag = 3;
        break;
    case KEY_LEFT:
        flag = 4;
        break;
    }
    
    if (x < 0 || x >= HEIGHT || y < 0 || y >= WIDTH)
    {
        gameover = 1;
    }
}

/* Commands and logic of the program */
void logic()
{
    switch(flag)
    {
        case 1:
            y--;
            break;
        case 2:
            y++;
            break;
        case 3:
            x++;
            break;
        case 4:
            x--;
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Initialize curses
    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE);

    // Game loop
    while (!gameover)
    {
        clear(); // Clear the screen
        boundary(HEIGHT, WIDTH); // Draw the game boundary and snake
        keyboard(); // Handle keyboard input
        logic(); // Update snake position
        refresh(); // Refresh the screen

        // Add a small delay for smooth movement
        //usleep(100000);
    }

    // Clean up curses
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using:

```
gcc snake.c -o snake -lncurses
```

What could be causing the blank terminal screen issue when running my C code with the curses library? Are there any common mistakes or additional steps I need to take to properly display the snake game?

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program? For example to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line, to see what really happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't mix stdio (`printf()`) with curses. If you change the printf calls to `printw()`, the square will be rendered. (I'd also suggest replacing the `usleep()` delay, if it were uncommented, with an equivalent call to curses' own `napms()` function (just divide the parameter by 1000).)